# Атрибуты шрифта

Tags: svg, шрифты, html, javascript

Интересует, где можно найти атрибуты моноширинных шрифтов. Очень интересует ширина символа, стандартный междустрочный интервал и др. Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался?

Сама задача состоит в том, чтобы внедрять в строку переносы в зависимости от ширины элемента **svg**, в который заданный текст должен быть вписан. Скрипт, вычисляющий ширину символа написал, но почему-то аспект для некоторых кеглей незначительно разнится.

Answer (score 1):

Расковырять любой шрифт можно в бесплатном редакторе [fontforge](http://fontforge.org). Ну а дальше только от фантазии и под задачу. Очень помог в своё время победить японскую двухбайтную хероганицу.

Answer (score 0):

Обязательно использовать svg?

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```